# Divert http non-www to http www, & https non-www to https www

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, server

The htaccess commands below divert all non-www to **http** www

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

How can one divert non-www to www with their respective **http/https**?

Comment: So, what this has to do with PHP?

Comment: Sorry. I'm a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code:

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS}:s on:(s)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]